# Can I merge Messages on my Mac?

Tags: time-machine, messages

I had previously asked this as part of [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272681/can-i-use-migration-assistant-to-migrate-certain-data-from-different-sources/272689#272689), but I realized it would be better if I kept them separate:

I have newer messages on one hard drive, and older messages on a Time Machine backup. How can I merge them?

Comment: Please specify your version of macOS and if you are referring to iMessages.app

Comment: @n1000 Sierra 10.12.4 Beta, and yes, it is Messages.app